# Kolmogorov inequality proof

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation, expected-value

I'm reading [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~psdey/MATH561SP19/week7.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Epsdey/MATH561SP19/week7.pdf) for a short proof on the Kolmogorov's inequality but I don't understand this line

> Then $$E(S_{n}^{2}) \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} E(S_{n}^{2} \mathbb{1}_{A_i}) = \dots$$

where $1_{A_i}$ is the indicator function on $A_i$. How can I interpret this first inequality? Thanks

Comment: You may find the discussion in Feller (Intro to Prob... Vol 1), page 220 useful.  https://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToProbabilityTheoryAndItsApplicationsVolume1/page/n239/mode/2up .  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\ A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset\ $ for $\ i\ne j\ $, as your source points out in the paragraph immediately preceding the inequality.  Therefore, $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_{A_i}= \mathbb{1}_{\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^nA_i}\le1\ $ with certainty, and since $\ S_n^2\ge0\ $ with certainty, then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n E\left(S_n^2 \mathbb{1}_{A_i}\right)=E \left(S_n^2 \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{A_i}\right)\le E\left(S_n^2\right)\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!